# stop bash from expanding * in sql statement

Tags: bash

i have a delete statement `delete * from table_name;`.  Currently shell expands it to list all existing files in current directory. How can i escape it, so that the string that is passed to sqlplus is indeed "delete * from table_name". I tried `\*` `'*'` and `\\*` and none of them work.

The exact script is

```
#!/bin/bash
table_name = $1
delete_sql= "delete * from $table_name;"
echo $delete_sql > abc.sql
```

Comment: How are you generating the statement?  Give the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to quote the variable (and fix your spacing around the `=` sign):

```
#!/bin/bash
table_name=$1
delete_sql="delete * from $table_name;"
echo "$delete_sql" > abc.sql
```

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
echo "delete * from table_name" | sqlplus
```

or

```
echo "delete * from table_name" > mystatements.txt
sqlplus @mystatements.txt
```

On a side note, you don't need to specify * in a delete statement - all fields in the matching rows are deleted.